# How to join 2 MATCH outputs in middle of cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to write work on a cypher query on neo4j browser version 3.1.4 (version change is not possible). My expertise level with cypher queries is quite beginner level

I have a query along below lines:

```
WITH SomeCollection

MATCH (x:xType)<- someRelationalMatchLogic which contains y as part of it             // FIRST MATCH PART
        WHERE (x.name = 'test') AND some logic on y

// SECOND MATCH PART

WITH x, y, SomeCollection
  WHERE some additional post processing based on x and y value and collection values
RETURN x
```

I would like following MATCH query to be inserted in above "// SECOND MATCH PART SECTION"

```
MATCH (x:xType)<- someDifferentReltionalMatchLogic which contains y as part of it
        WHERE (x.name = 'test') AND some logic on y
```

So that I can get a joint / union match result before proceeding with remainder of query.

Currently my only working option is I copy paste full query, and use the 2nd match block instead of first in pasted section, and use UNION between the 2.

Given the actual query before and after MATCH is pretty big, it seems a very dirty and inefficient approach.

The only other approach I could think of based on my searches was CALL subquery with UNION usage is subquery for 2 MATCH as demostrated here https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call-subquery/

But for some reason this CALL approach is giving errors in my neo4j version, I thought I was may be incorrectly writing my query, so I directly used first example in link and even that gave error
E.g. used from link:

```
UNWIND [0, 1, 2] AS x
CALL {
  WITH x
  RETURN x * 10 AS y
}
RETURN x, y
```

Error(s):

```
mismatched input '{' expecting {HexLetter, CYPHER, EXPLAIN, PROFILE, USING, PERIODIC, COMMIT, UNION, ALL, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ON, CONSTRAINT, ASSERT, IS, UNIQUE, EXISTS, LOAD, CSV, WITH, HEADERS, FROM, AS, FIELDTERMINATOR, OPTIONAL, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, SET, DETACH, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, IN, DISTINCT, RETURN, ORDER, BY, L_SKIP, LIMIT, ASCENDING, ASC, DESCENDING, DESC, JOIN, SCAN, START, NODE, RELATIONSHIP, REL, WHERE, SHORTESTPATH, ALLSHORTESTPATHS, OR, XOR, AND, NOT, STARTS, ENDS, CONTAINS, NULL, COUNT, FILTER, EXTRACT, ANY, NONE, SINGLE, TRUE, FALSE, REDUCE, CASE, ELSE, END, WHEN, THEN, CALL, YIELD, KEY, UnescapedSymbolicName, EscapedSymbolicName}
```

[image]

AND

```
extraneous input 'x' expecting {';', '(', UNION, CREATE, LOAD, WITH, OPTIONAL, MATCH, UNWIND, MERGE, SET, DETACH, DELETE, REMOVE, FOREACH, RETURN, START, CALL, YIELD, SP}
```

[image]

Any inputs towards addressing this CALL error, and / or helping achieve the join x and y output of those 2 MATCH blocks in that query section before proceeding further through any alternate suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: CALL {} sub query clauses are only from Neo4j 4.x onwards

Comment: Can you specify your actual "match logic" or what your actual use case is? The question is currently too ambiguous.